# Wait service postgres start dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using docker file to build ubuntu image have install postgresql. But I can't wait for service postgres status OK

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
....
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-11
RUN service postgresql start
RUN su postgres
RUN psql
RUN CREATE USER kong; CREATE DATABASE kong OWNER kong;
RUN \q
RUN exit
```

Everything seem okay, but `RUN su postgres` will throw error because service postgresql not yet started after `RUN service postgresql start`. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @Akashii, sorry for asking. Any reason why you need to build your own postgresql image? I think you better use `postgres` as base image. It's already in docker hub `https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, each RUN command in Dockerfile run in a separate shell and `RUN` command should be used for installation or configuration not for `starting` the process. The process should be started at `CMD` or `entrypoint`.

[RUN vs CMD](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/)

Better to use offical [postgress docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

The default postgres user and database are created in the entrypoint with initdb.
or you can build your image based on  postgress.

```
FROM postgres:11
ENV POSTGRES_USER=kong
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
COPY seed.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
```

This will create an image with user, password and also the entrypoint will insert seed data as well when container started.

**POSTGRES_USER**

> This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with
>   POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will
>   create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the
>   same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of postgres
>   will be used.

Some advantage with offical docker image

- Create DB from ENV
- Create DB user from ENV
- Start container with seed data
- Will wait for postgres to be up and running

All you need

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

**Initialization scripts**

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived
>   from this one, add one or more `*.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh` scripts under
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (creating the directory if necessary).
>   After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user
>   and database, it will run any `*.sql` files, run any executable *.sh
>   scripts, and source any non-executable `*.sh` scripts found in that
>   directory to do further initialization before starting the service.